# Fetch polyfill has different Response-object in internet explorer 11

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer, babeljs, fetch-api, polyfills

I'm currently struggeling with `Internet Explorer 11` and the `Fetch API`.

I have the following fetch-call unsing `TypeScript`:

```
await fetch(theForm.action, { method: theForm.method, body: formData, credentials: "include" })
    .then((response: Response) => {
        if (response.status === 500)
            throw Error(response.statusText);

        if (response.redirected && response.url)
            return window.location.href = response.url;

        return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        return this.setState({ isSubmitting: false, internalServerError: error });
    });
```

The code is ts-compiled to `ES2015` and then down to `ES5` using babel. I've also added `babel-polyfill`. The example code works as expected on other browsers than IE.
As it turns out, the `Response`-object in IE is totally different and don't even has the property `redirected` and `url` is always empty.

Is there any polyfill I should use to make this work in IE? And, if not, what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

[MDN's browser compatibility table for `Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) says that the `redirected` attribute isn't available on IE.

[image: MDN's browser compatibility table for <code>Response</code>]

You could try using a polyfill like https://github.com/github/fetch along with the API suggestion on https://github.com/github/fetch#obtaining-the-response-url.